# the difference between a[b+1] and a[b+1'b1]

Tags: verilog

when I try to write to a[b+1] where the bits of b are all '1' ,the value of the reg a[0] do not update,but when I try a[b+1'b1],it updated

```
  awaddr_wa              <= awaddr_wa + 2;
  awaddr[awaddr_wa]      <= AWADDR_M;
  awlen [awaddr_wa]      <= 4'd0;
  awaddr[awaddr_wa+6'd1] <= AWADDR_M+16;
  awlen [awaddr_wa+6'd1] <= 4'd0
```

so ,why?

Comment: `1'b` is **1** bit wide, just `1` is **32** bit wide. not sure how it could change the results in your case though. You need to provide a reproducer example.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
module M;

  integer a[0:7] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  reg [2:0] b = -1;

  initial
    begin
      $display("a[b+1]=", a[b+1]);
      $display("a[b+1'b1]=", b+1'b1);
    end

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/26Za

(Your question would be better had it included this)

You will see that the output is something like:

```
a[b+1]=          x 
a[b+1'b1]=0
```

1. `1` is 32 bits wide. (All unbased literals in Verilog are 32 bits
   wide.)
2. When you mix bit widths like this in Verilog, Verilog must
   decide how many bits to use.
3. When you index an array out of range in Verilog this is not a catastrophe like it is in C. Instead the default value for the type of the array is returned. `a` is an array of `integer`s, whose default value is `32'bx`.
4. With `a[b+1]`, Verilog will take the wider of 3 bits (`b`) and 32 bits (`1`), ie 32 bits. So, with `b=3'b111`, `1` is added to `b` using *32-bit* arithmetic. In 32-bit arithmetic, 7+1 is 8, so `a[b+1]` is the same as `a[8]` which is out of range and hence `32'bx`.
5. With `a[b+1'b1]`, Verilog will take the wider of 3 bits (`b`) and 1 bit (`1'b1`), ie 3 bits. So, with `b=3'b111`, `1'b1` is added to `b` using *3-bit* arithmetic. In 3-bit arithmetic, 7+1 is 0, so `a[b+1'b1]` is the same as `a[0]` which is *not* out of range and is `32'b0` in my example.

This is a classic trap in Verilog. It is an example of a Verilog *self-determined expression*. A self-determined expression is one where the number of bits used for the calculation depends only the widths of the operands. There are also *context-determined expressions* (eg `F = A + B`) where the number of bits also depends on the width of the variable (or net) being assigned to.

Comment: Neat! I would expect the same result from both of these.

Comment: @CharlesClayton Thank you. I've added some more info which might be of help (the last paragraph).

Comment: Minor point: if a mem/array address is unknown or out of range the language is defined to return `x`, irrespective of the type of the elements. In Verilog, anyway; don't know about SV.