# Diference in bit selection in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a code similar to the following

```
module testModule(
    input        Clk,
    input  [2:0] Counter,
    output [1:0] OutVar1,
    output [1:0] OutVar2
);

    localparam logic [7:0] mask = 8'h50;

    // CODE 1
    always_ff @(posedge Clk) begin
        case (mask[{Counter[1:0], 1'b0} +: 2])
            2'h0 : OutVar1 <= 2'h0;
            2'h1 : OutVar1 <= 2'h1;
            2'h2 : OutVar1 <= 2'h2;
            2'h3 : OutVar1 <= 2'h3;
            default: OutVar1 <= 2'hX;
        endcase
    end

    // CODE 2
    always_ff @(posedge Clk) begin
        case (mask[(Counter[1:0]<<1) +: 2])
            2'h0 : OutVar2 <= 2'h0;
            2'h1 : OutVar2 <= 2'h1;
            2'h2 : OutVar2 <= 2'h2;
            2'h3 : OutVar2 <= 2'h3;
            default: OutVar2 <= 2'hX;
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

Counter is a input that goes 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 2, 4, etc.
And I expected CODE 1 and CODE 2 to behave the same but when counter is 2 and 6 (counter[1:0] is 2) I hit the case 2'h1 in CODE 1 (correct) and 2'h0 in CODE 2 (wrong).

I have not checked yet what is the behaviour if counter goes 0, 1, ..., 7, 0, 1, etc.

I do not have a testbed because this code is part of a large project. I saw the problem after simulation and seeing the waves.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have updated the question, mask value was 0x50 (it is assing somewhere else in the code) but as far as this question is concerned it can be a constant value of 8 bits.

Comment: the code in your example makes no sense. what are all those quoted strings mean?

Comment: The quoted strings are placeholders. In my code I have assigments of other variables, but it is irrelevant

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're missing that only 2 bits are used to calculate the answer in "CODE 2", because it is a so-called *self-determined expression*. So, Verilog takes the expression:

```
counter[1:0]<<1
```

and needs to decide how many bits to use for the answer. This is what it does: it looks at how many bits there are on the left hand side of the shift operator (2) and uses that to put the result in. How could it do anything else? The number of bits on the right hand side (32) is basically irrelevant (unless you think Verilog should use 2^31-1 bits for the result!). So, you get an overflow - the left hand side of the result of the shift is truncated.

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690004/the-difference-between-ab1-and-ab1b1/57693445#57693445).

Comment: This was my first idea but I had the following code working properly

`logic [1:0] counter;`
`... (same code as before)...`
`// CODE 2`
`case (mask[(counter<<1) +: 2])`
`... (same code as before)...`

Comment: this should fix your code: `mask[({1'b0, Counter[1:0]}<<1)`

Comment: The first version of the code already solves it. I just wanted to understand why the other one was failing